# OrientDB Match with an Edge Property

Tags: orientdb

I have this graph:

```
Regione -Ha-> Deceduto -alGiornoDeceduti -> Data
```

and the `alGiornoDeceduti` edge has the property `name`. I am trying this query, but it is not working:

```
match {class:Regione, as:r} -Ha-> {class:Deceduto, as:d} .outE("alGiornoDeceduti"){where:(name=r.name)}.inV() {class:Data, as:dd, where:(data="2020-05-03 00:00:00")} return r.name,d.deceduti,dd.data
```

I think the error is this:

```
{where:(name=r.name)}
```

because if I replace the `r.name` with for example 'Sardinia' it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to other nodes in the pattern using the `$matched` keyword, eg.

```
name = $matched.r.name
```